# Spec of $k(X)$ is the fibre of $f$ over the generic point of $Y$ given $f: X \to Y$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, affine-schemes

I am trying to understand a part of proof of Corollary 2  in Section III. 5
in Mumford's Red book.

Suppose I have an etale dominant morphism $f: X \to Y$ where $X$ and $Y$ are separated irreducible reduced scheme of finite type over an algebraically closed field.

He states that the Spec of $k(X)$, the function field of $X$, is the fibre of $f$ over the generic point of $Y$.

How can I prove the statement?
I think I have covered all the assumptions in the proof, but the example provided in the comment looks like a counterexample... I would appreciate any clarification or explanation on this. Thank you.

ps In this section Mumford defines etale for $f$ of finite type.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the projection $\mathbb{A}^2\to \mathbb{A}^1$ ?

Comment: Let me change the question

Comment: The same example I gave shows that the étale condition is needed for the statement (the projection $\mathbb{A}^2\to \mathbb{A}^1$ is clearly not étale, for instance).

Comment: oops yes, let me just add etale

Comment: Consider a map $X \rightarrow Y$ of elliptic curves over $k$ of degree $d > 1$. It satisfies all of the given hypotheses, but the generic fiber has $d$ elements.

Comment: I'm trying to understand a part of a proof in Mumford. I will add this in the question.

Comment: Consider an etale morphism $X \to Y$ of elliptic curves of degree $d>1$, then this corresponds to an unramified extension of the function fields $k(Y) \subset k(X)$. The degree of the morphism $\operatorname{Spec} k(X) \to \operatorname{Spec} k(Y)$ will be equal to $d$, but $\operatorname{Spec} k(X)$ is irreducible. Of course if we look at a geometric generic fibre (base change to the algebraic closure of the generic point of $Y$), then the fiber will be a disjoint union of $d$ points.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\eta=\operatorname{Spec}k(Y)$ be the generic point of $Y$, then if we basechange $X \to Y$ via $\eta \to Y$ then we get $X_{\eta} \to \operatorname{Spec}k(Y)$, which will be étale. In other words, we have a finite étale algebra $A$ over $k(Y)$ of degree $d$ with spectrum equal to $X_{\eta}$, and we want to show that $A \simeq k(X)$ as $k(Y)$ algebras.

But the universal property of the fiber product gives us a map $A \to k(X)$ of $k(Y)$-algebras, and to prove that this is an isomorphism it suffices to prove that it is injective [because it is a morphism of finite dimensional $k(Y)$ vector spaces of the same rank].

To show that it is injective, it suffices to show that $A$ is a field. First of all we know that $X_{\eta}$ is homeomorphic to $f^{-1}(X_{\eta})$ [c.f. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2439943/45878], and so that $\operatorname{Spec} A$ has precisely one point. Indeed, the only point of $X$ that maps to the generic point of $Y$ is the generic point of $X$, because $X$ and $Y$ are equidimensional. It follows that $A$ is the spectrum of a finite field extension of $k(Y)$ (an étale algebra over a field is always a product of finite field extensions).

Comment: How do we know that $A$ and $K(X)$ have the same rank?

Comment: Also what exactly is $A$ here?

Comment: I have used $A$ to denote the $k(Y)$-algebra with $\operatorname{Spec} A= X_{\eta}$. We know that the ranks are the same because the degree of a finite étale morphism is constant (and it can be computed on the generic points as the degree of the field extension).

Comment: I see, thank you. I don't quite follow how we know $X_{\eta}$ is an affine scheme...

Comment: Finite morphisms are in particular affine, so if we basechange by an affine scheme (e.g. the generic point of $Y$), then we get an affine scheme over $\operatorname{Spec} k(Y)$.